# HTML 5 form validation support in IE 10 ? and mobile?

Tags: html, forms, validation

I use `HTML 5 form validation` and i noticed that in `IE 10.x` doesn't work. 
Specifically, I use this:

```
.validity.valid
.validity.valueMissing
```

Is there another way to use HTML 5 also on IE 10.x ? and on mobile (safari, chrome ecc) how goes ?